# I don't understand this hexeditor output

Tags: hex

I'm trying extract .wav files from a datafile, and each file has some metadata at the end of it.
It contains a date, '1996-05-16' as shown here:

[image]

Most of these dates for the files are correct, but some have special chars in them, like here:

[image]

What's going on? I'm using the HxD editor.

edit: also seeing these zeros between 'RIFF' which should be a complete word/identifier for WAV files. Is the data corrupted? I get the feeling the .EXE might be doing some decoding on this data?
[image]

Comment: You mean the 0x04  it normally indicates[ end of text , end of data or ctrl+D ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character)

Comment: I see, and the 0x020 befire it is a space right..but what is it doing right in the middle of a date? I doubt it's been entered like that originally, so maybe a property of the metadata of the wav?

Comment: Probably corrupt you can see S in SoundForge is different charecter in one screen shot  you posted

Comment: I think I found the problem..the data is slightly compressed, I found this in the log: 1io_Io(457)      processing volume: white1s.vol
1io_Io(466)      allocating 496kB...
1io_Io(476)      reading and decompressing 467kB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some form of [run length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) could be custom since it's quite simple to write. You can lookup run length encoding in TGA image files for a code example. But personally I would first check if it's LZ4 since that uses RLE. You will likely need to use the LZ4 api if so. I would write a for loop that attempts to LZ4 inflate at offset 0,1,2,3,... and see if any complete without error and have an expected size.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a nice start to look into this

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my file has some sort of compression, I just found this info in the logs of the game that's using the datafile:

```
1io_Io(457)      processing volume: white1s.vol
1io_Io(466)      allocating 496kB...
1io_Io(476)      reading and decompressing 467kB...
```

Now I'll have to dive into a debugger to see what's going on